# Change selected cell outline color

Tags: excel

I am trying to change the color of the selected cell color, which is green in this screenshot for Office 2013. I would like to change it to red.

How do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Go to the File tab --> Options --> Advanced --> and there is a section called "Display options for this worksheet:"

Change the drop down to select the workbook. Change the Gridline colour.

Comment: thanks but that changes the gridlines, not the selected cell outline